# how to remove prettier code-formatter plugin completely in vs code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I uninstall the **prettier code-formatter**  plugin by uninstalling button but when I save the react js file it automatically formats the code.

Here what setting.json file looks like

```
{
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"window.zoomLevel": 1,
"editor.fontFamily": "Monaco, Menlo, 'Courier New', monospace",
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"npm.enableScriptExplorer": true,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"debug.node.autoAttach": "on",
"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 2,
"prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
},
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"prettier.endOfLine": "auto",
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
"git.autofetch": true,
"[ruby]": {},
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash"
```

}

I  want to know how to get rid of the  **esbenp.prettier-vscode**.

Answer (score 4):

open command palette > Format Document With... > Configure Default Formatter

You need to have an HTML file open in your active tab. That should give you the option of picking the builtin HTML language features and consequently change the value of the respective setting in your JSON.

To disable formatting altogether you need to uncheck "Format On Save" and "Format on Type" or edit the respective `"editor.formatOnSave"` and `"editor.formatOnType"` fields with a `false` value.

Comment: can you tell me the full path to **"editor.formatOnSave"** and **"editor.formatOnType"**?.

Comment: all your settings - unless you have workspace settings - are in the _settings.json_ that you referenced in your question. It might be easier for you to use the settings UI. You can open that with ⌘ +, (Ctrl+,) and search for "Format"